# copying logs when ec2 shutting down in aws linux2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I recently got to know about amazon launches linux2 with some upgrade on os side, so I decided to try it.
while exploring linux 2 I found there are many changes done. Service defination moved from /etc/init.d/ to /usr/lib/systemd/system/ and there is not /etc/init/

One problem I am facing with linux 2 is when instance shutting down there is no signal that system going to power off. Here we are facing trouble.

We want to copy logs when system shutting down. in normal amazon linux we written job in /etc/init which execute when runlevel changes and execute our script to copy log but here in linux 2 there is nothing like this.

I gone ahead and write my own service defination at /usr/lib/systemd/system and put script which must execute when system shutting down at /etc/ but its not working

My service definition is

```
[Unit]    
Description=copy to s3    
Before=shutdown.target

[Service]    
ExecStart=/bin/true    
ExecStop=/etc/end.sh    
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]    
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If some one can help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest you not to rely on shutdown hooks for log backup since the time window you receive might not be enough. Instead use cloudwatch to regularly send the logs.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html

Comment: HI Anuruddha, thanks for reply. How ever our requirement is something different. we want to rename original log  file name with some specific name which I guess not possible with cloudwatch logs. So want to depend on script.